# Mousedown triggers event, then when mouse is moved off element and mouseup fires it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

http://jsfiddle.net/63Y54/2/

In the example above when the user clicks and drags left or right off the canvas while holding the mouse button down and then takes their finger off the mouse the oscillator note hangs. I want to fix this. I am curious if their is a simple way to do something like..

```
if (mouseup == !htmlElement){
     then....
}
```

In this case the html element would be the canvas element as that is what the user is clicking on.

As an attempt to fix this I made the body element encompass the page by setting its CSS width and height to 100%.

I then created a function that selected the body element with a mouseup click handler that launches the oscillator.stop() method. This only works when the user moved their mouse to the side of the page but when they moved *down* it still creates a hanging note.

This pseudo solution is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/63Y54/5/

Comment: Are you try for `$(document).mouseout()` ,because your hanging condition is occurs when your mouse goes outside of the body..

Comment: This works, but I'm still curious if their is anything that resembles my 'mouseup == !htmlElement' pseudo code above

Comment: ,In the `document`, all elements are of HTML, So only you have the way to detect `mouseout` or `mouseup` with in those element,or another is to use `.blur()` if focus out form you `canvas` then `oscillator.stop();` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this similar question answers yours.

[jQuery detect mousedown inside an element and then mouseup outside the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309912/jquery-detect-mousedown-inside-an-element-and-then-mouseup-outside-the-element)

Here is the code from it from a guy named Mike:

```
    var isDown = false;

    $("#element").mousedown(function(){
         isDown = true;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        if(isDown){
            //do something
        isDown = false;
    }
```

There is additional code handling fringe cases in thelink as well.