# JavaScript mouse up event does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

The following is the code that we use to detect if the mouse is up or down.

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    mouseDown = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    mouseDown = false;
});
```

We need the mouse status later for drawing operations. One problem that we have is that when we select something and drag it, mouse down event fires but mouse up does not. What can we do to set `mouseDown` false when the mouse is up in this kind of situation.

Comment: I dont see anythign wrong with this code, may be something else is messed up.anyway you can refer to this jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/9UVsL/ for understanding how to get dynamic `x,y` points on a canvas

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var isDown = false;

$("document").mousedown(function(){
    isDown = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    if(isDown){
        //do something
        isDown = false;
    }
});
```

Also try using delegation
Source : [jQuery detect mousedown inside an element and then mouseup outside the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309912/jquery-detect-mousedown-inside-an-element-and-then-mouseup-outside-the-element)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't seem to be what's going on here.